# Spring security + Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContextunauthorized problem

Tags: spring, security

when I try to call swagger pages with url http://localhost:8080/demo_war/api/swagger-ui.html, I obtain error An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContextunauthorized problem. I add Security config like

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/api/swagger-ui.html")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html");
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work. Do someone know, how to face this issue?

Comment: `.permitAll()` is your best friend :)

Comment: I dont want to permit all, but only disable security for /api/swagger-ui.html :-(

Comment: what is a difference between `permitAll` and disabled security for specific api? `permitAll` works with specific `antMatchers`

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: check answers :)

Answer (score 0):

See description of "ignoring" method here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html

Comment: You should permit all or make it available anonymous.

When you use WebSecurity#ignoring() you don't have SecurityContext at all (security filters are skipped), so you cannot access Authorization data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your configuratuon
`.antMatchers("/api/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()`
Please check a [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html) for future cases